# Configuring nginx web server with multiple app server of aws stack

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, webserver

I am a DevOps guy and presently I am running my Ruby on Rails application on ubuntu ec2 where the app and also the web server reside inside the same box but we are using mysql RDS cluster. I can see lot of spikes due to more traffic to the web site. So I am planning to change the system. I wanna put web server nginx in a separate instance and web app in a separate instance. But this needs a load balancer which should reside in nginx box, but once the traffic goes up, the nginx instance can be configured to auto scale. What about the app server instance? It can be configured to auto scale but it needs to attach itself to the web server and web server needs to discover the new app server which was created. How can achieve this? Kindly help me out to get this done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using one single web server at the moment, a transition to using nginx as static webserver and proxy for another backend webserver on another instance really makes sense and will give you performance boost.

However I am not sure if you really need autoscaling. Autoscaling mostly makes sense if you want to react on fast traffic spikes etc. If you have a more or less continuous workload that might increase over time, it should be easier to manually launch and add another backend server in the nginx config. If this does not work for you, you can still have a look at [Amazon's Elastic Loadbalancers](http://aws.amazon.com/de/elasticloadbalancing/) and Autoscaling afterwards.

Comment: I can get unexpected traffic some times so that the reason the nginx webserver instance will be configured for auto scaling and hence its will put under LB.

Comment: In this case I would add an ELB behind nginx. In nginx direct all backend traffic to the ELB. Behind the ELB you can have your auto scaling group with different app servers. They can scale up and down without the need to change nginx configuration.

Comment: I think you would want to have 2 ELB's. Depending on traffic. One in front of the web servers, and one in front of the app servers. Then you can autoscale both independently as needed.